# Completing Proof of Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I came across the following document, which includes proofs of lemmas relating to the F.T.F.A.G. http://witno.com/philadelphia/notes/won7.pdf

The final lemma (Lemma 10) peaked my interest, as this proves the theorem for the case where the order of the group is a power of some prime. How can we extend this lemma to the case where the order of the group is not a power of a prime? What further result would we need?

Comment: The simplest case not covered by that lemma would be a group of order $pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are *distinct* primes. What happens in this case? In light of that answer, what are the possibilities for $p^kq$? What about $p^kq^j$?

Comment: Yes, it was the case of $pq$ that I was struggling to prove.

Comment: Hint: There must be a subgroup of size $p$ and one of size $q$, and because those numbers are prime, those subgroups must be cyclic (why?). From this, we know we can find a single element in each subgroup that generates the whole subgroup, e.g. $a$ for the subgroup of size $p$ and $b$ likewise for $q$. They must commute because our entire group is declared to be abelian *a priori*, so...what is the order of $ab$?

Comment: I understand the reasoning there, but how does one then prove that there is an isomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q$? It looks similar to the Chinese Remainder Theorem in this form, so is it true that $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. There is a reason I asked you what the order of $ab$ is. It turns out that it must be order $pq$, which implies that it generates a cyclic group with $pq$ elements, or in other words, that our group of order $pq$, must be $\mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful.